# How does a step-up voltage converter work?

Tags: voltage

How does a step-up voltage converter work? I am talking about DC amplified to DC.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding DC-DC boost converters](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/443907/understanding-dc-dc-boost-converters)

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: @GabrielKusiak that's not an amplifier. an amplifier amplifies the input, e.g. when the input voltage increases by 10%, the output voltage increases by 10%. A boost converter typically keeps the output voltage constants, for any input voltage within the working range. So, wrong word!

Comment: Fundamentally, by stepping down the current to match the voltage stepup, thanks to conservation of energy. That can result in high input currents.